# rm command crashed my server

Tags: linux, centos, rm, delete

I ran the following command `find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm -f {} \;` on my centos server in the attempt to free some space. After running this command my server crashed. I had to restore from a backup VM. This command has worked before on some of my servers. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I recommend that you look at the logs.

Comment: You possibly had a runaway process writing to disk and the system crashed when it ran out of space.

Comment: If you were root when you issued the command you may have erased files that are used by service daemons.

Comment: What kind of crash? Kernel panic? or something else?